# Google shopping content API - targeting both local and non local listings with same feed

Tags: google-api, google-content-api, google-merchant-center

when I create a feed of type "products" targeting "shopping", in the UI I have a toggle to have it targeting local listings as well.

Is there a way to achieve that functionality through API? Have one feed targeting both local and non local listings?

I believe that's better since that way I'll use half the products' quota to cover both use cases, right?

Once I manually do that, and call GET on the feed, I see "LocalSurfacesAcrossGoogle" added to the includedDestinations, but trying to update a feed with that value throws an error (also it doesn't appear on the docs as a valid value.

Comment: I wonder if you have found any solution/answer to your question.